# Function to apply parameter specified soft-cap at y = 1?

Tags: limits, functions, continuity

I am writing some code that requires some form of soft limits to the input. A hard cap I understand to be something like:

```
y = x;
if (y > 1) y = 1;
```

But in my case, I would like to soften the cap, so that we smoothly asymptote towards the limiting value, the smoothness specified by some other parameter (e.g. `a`).

Excuse the bad drawing:

[image: graph]

The sigmoid functions I have looked at do not seem to be able to modified to allow a parameter to change their smoothness, without violating `y > x` at early values.

Any suggestions are appreciated!